# A digit in a numeral system, a "symbol"?

Tags: single-word-requests

While explaining numeral systems, I found myself using the phrase "add a digit" twice, with two different meanings;

- To create a new symbol with an associated value and introduce it into the numeral system, thus increasing the radix by one.
- To add an existing symbol from the numeral system into a numeral, thus increasing the length of the sequence by one.

Is there an easy way to disambiguate these different meanings? More specifically I would like to know if there are two different words to represent a digit in the context of a numeral system and in the context of an actual numeral. Would "symbol" be correct in the context of a numeral system?

Comment: I tend to think of *symbols* in mathematics as things like plus, minus, equals signs etc. The actual figures are either *digits* or *numerals*. Of course an *algebraic symbol* would refer to a letter of the alphabet, either Greek or Roman.

Comment: You might disambiguate the **action,** perhaps using *introduce* for the first (as you did) and *append* for the second. But I admit that I'm not sure what your second example is actually describing.

Comment: The second example is what would happen when you increase the number 9 by one. In addition to changing the digits that were already in the sequence, the length of the sequence has to be increased.

Comment: OK. So adding ten to "9" we *append* (or *prepend*) the digit 1 to the existing string of digits. [Shades of string-handling and type-conversion here, which screams "Wrong!" but hopefully it's clear]

Comment: Can you give an example for each of your bullet points?

Comment: Any time you're discussing systems of symbols you need to very consciously layout your terminology.  It's not an after-thought.

Comment: The verbs you use can yield a great deal of clarity.

Comment: who would downvote such a good question?

Answer (score 1):

By the usual English dictionary definition this is one of the symbols 0 - 9

> Definition of digit in English:   noun
>
> 1 Any of the numerals from 0 to 9, especially when forming part of a
>   number.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/digit)
>
> ---

When doing mathematics, you are entitled to define terms and it would make sense to call extra symbols that you introduce, 'digits'. Thus in hexadecimal we get the digits 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F

If you are working in hex and 'add' one of these predefined symbols  to an exisiting string, then you have clearly added a digit.

If you change your base, then you may need to *introduce* new symbols. These can be arbitrary according to your choice as long as you state it in advance, e.g.

0 1 2 3 4 f q > 8 9

**Answer**

So, yes. Use the term *symbol* and allocate a meaning to it by definition. Once you have done that, the symbol can be used as a digit.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't two different terms for a digit. But there are a whole bunch of different operations referred to as *adding*. Your first example is adding a new member to a digit set. You just have to get across the idea of a set somehow. The second example is adding to a digit string, and you have to get that context across somehow. The digits that take part in these operations are exactly the same things, and this is a point that wants emphasis, not muddying-up.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a symbol or a group of symbols at the end or beginning of a word (the latter meaning a group of symbols) is *concatenation* (this is the usual mathematical term for this process; *stringing together* is often used).

The first operation is enlarging the set of symbols.

Normally, the set of symbols used for stringing together (concatenation) is known as the *alphabet*, but this could be confusing in your case. So the first operation is enlarging the alphabet, the second is concatenation.

And of course, symbols don't have to be Greek or latin characters; Cyrillic and Hebrew letters also occur standardly in mathematics, along with hundreds of others that don't belong to any alphabet (in the non-mathematical sense).